# Operation count for Tridiagonal System

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

What is the operation count for solving the tridiagonal system $Ax=b$. I would guess it is $O(n^2)$ because all we are doing is making one sub-diagonal zero all the way across giving us $t(n)=n$ and another $n$ operations for backsolving. I can't confirm this because I couldn't find any article that talks about this. Any help is appreciated with some link for further reading.

Comment: Using LU factorization, you need only to eliminate entries on the lower diagonal (no need to eliminate entries, which are already zero). Both $L$ and $U$ factors have two diagonals only and the cost is $O(n)$.

Comment: Btw : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm